# I have module installed but jupyter notebook throws an error - No module name : xxxx

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pip

I made a virtual environment called tfhg in "D:\Machine Learning\Hand Gesture\tfhg"

Then I wrote the following piece of code:

```
!pip install tensorflow opencv-python mediapipe scikit-learn matplotlib

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2
import time
import mediapipe as mp
```

Checked my package list using

```
!pip list
```

[image]

while running the import statement first I got an error - No module named 'cv2' then when I commented that line I got another error which says - No module named mediapipe. I am confused because I can see both the packages in my folder as well as in the pip list.

import statements:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2
import time
import mediapipe as mp
```

I restarted the kernel and re-run everything but it didn't work. Then I re-installed the packages by uninstalling and re-installing but it didn't work either.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure if `jupyter` is using the interpreter you've specified with `pip`. I would highly recommend using `python -m pip install <module>` and `python -m jupyter notebook` to manage the environment. This way you will be sure that the interpreter you've installed those modules to is the same one that your jupyter notebook is tied to.

Note: `python -m pip install tensorflow opencv-python mediapipe scikit-learn matplotlib` should be run in a shell (cmd/bash/powershell), not jupyter

Comment: Thanks for helping out mate but it was just a missing step while initiating the virtual environment. I was following gfg's method to create and activate the virtual environment. In the tutorial, the author used ipython (I am not sure about the technicalities) but when I followed another tutorial which involves installing ipykernel and then connecting my env to the kernel everything worked smoothly. If you know what is the difference between using ipython and ipykernel, it'd be greatly helpful. Thanks again.